# tensorflow Core (not Keras) code for intermediate layers

Tags: tensorflow, loss-function

I want to implement code in the TensorFlow core for determining loss between intermediate layers of two networks(**knowledge distillation**) in my thesis.

In the case of ResNet_18 (Customized), the 8th layer has the dimension of <None, 8, 8, 64>.

I can`t find practical code for this problem in the TensorFlow Core (not Keras) form.

What loss do you suggest?

Thanks a lot,

I just try to implement the modified loss according to [FEED- Feature-level Ensemble Knowledge Distillation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.10754) without NTL (for simplification). But it didn't work:

```
fA2 = fADiv(logitsFeatures)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(fA1-fA2), axis=[1, 2])
#
def fADiv(input):
    fA = tf.reduce_mean(tf.multiply(input, input), axis=3)
    temp1 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.abs(fA), axis=[1, 2])
    temp1 = tf.expand_dims(temp1, -1)
    temp1 = tf.repeat(temp1, 8, axis=1, name=None)
    temp1 = tf.expand_dims(temp1, -1)
    temp1 = tf.repeat(temp1, 8, axis=2, name=None)
    featureReduceFinal = tf.math.divide(fA, temp1)
    return featureReduceFinal
```

(Sorry for the bad English :) )

Comment: You should be able to apply the [distillation tutorial](https://keras.io/examples/vision/knowledge_distillation/) from the keras website using `tf.keras`. 
I'm voting to close your question because it does not fit the requirements for this website: it lacks focus, needs some debugging details (what did you try, are you facing an error?), and is looking for recommendation for tools or guides. If you have a more defined issue, don't hesitate to come back and ask it here though. :)

Comment: Thanks, I added my last attempt and code.